# How can i start WebRTC sample application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, webrtc

I've read a lot of documents about webRTC. Now I want to implement a sample application. I went through [this useful stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172627/working-hello-world-webrtc-datachannel-examples-with-signaling-implemented?noredirect=1&lq=1).

And I got some client, a server in Javascript. I don't know how to start to see this demo . What are the steps should I take?

They explained like :

```
signaling technology: WebSockets
client: pure html/javascript
server: node.js, ws
last tested on: Firefox 40.0.2, Chrome 44.0.2403.157 m, Opera 31.0.1889.174
```

I understand this but I don't have much practical knowledge on this. These are my questions to setup this demo ?

- Should I have a `hosting account` ? or can I use this with my
  `localhost` ?
- Next , where should I done this `node.js, ws` ? can I use with `linux
  machine` and install `npm` and run the `server.js` file on that ?
- How can I start `client.js` code on my Linux machine ?
- Only `server.js` and `client.js` file is required to setup this
  application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new with WebRTC too, but i hope my answer can satisfy you

1. You can use that demo in localhost
2. You can install nodejs in linux machine and run `server.js` on that.
3. To run the demo

   - run `server.js` through nodejs. Make sure you installed `ws` package first.
   - then you create a directory name `static` and put `client-side code` in there.
   - open your browser and go to `localhost:80` to see the demo.
4. Yes, you just need 2 files to setup that application. The client file in [Working Hello World WebRTC DataChannel Examples with Signaling Implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172627/working-hello-world-webrtc-datachannel-examples-with-signaling-implemented?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a html file not javascript.

You can see another tutorial in here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_environment.htm

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: how can i run that HTML file ? just double click ? or any other node commands required ? and i got  another sample from http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/create-your-own-videochat-application-with-html-and-javascript  but when i load localhost:portno it is opening , still loading . Any pblm ?

Comment: Do you load localhost with port which server is listening?

Comment: If the port is correct and page still loading, i think it is server's issue.

Comment: ok . i will check that . But how should i run HTML code ? simple run enough ?

Comment: In server code has `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static')); // client code goes in static directory`. So when you load localhost:port-server-listen, it will automatically load your default html file (index.html) in that directory. If your directory has client.html, you can access it through localhost:portno/client.html

Comment: inside the server code , `wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server, port: 8000 });` . what should i add for server ? i am not hosting an server . i just copy on Linux machine folder  . i got error on this line when i run server.js

Comment: Did you install `ws` package? Also, you have to install `express` package too.